# Error infor: bits operated on 'chisel3.core.Bool@32' must be hardware, not a bare Chisel type

Tags: chisel

I had my queue code as below:

```
class LocalQueue[T <: Data](gen: T, val entries: Int,
                       pipe: Boolean = false,
                       flow: Boolean = false) extends Module

{

  /** The I/O for this queue */



  val io = new QueueIO(gen, entries)

  /....../

  val init_done        = RegInit(0.U(1.W))

  val tick_cnt         = RegInit(0.U(1.W))


  val do_enq = io.enq.valid && io.enq.ready && (1.U === init_done) && (0.U === tick_cnt)

  val do_deq = io.deq.ready && io.deq.valid && (1.U === init_done) && (1.U === tick_cnt)
```

When I compile, got below error log:

> [error] (run-main-3a) chisel3.core.Binding$ExpectedHardwareException:
>   bits operated on 'chisel3.core.Bool@32' must be hardware, not a bare
>   Chisel type chisel3.core.Binding$ExpectedHardwareException: bits
>   operated on 'chisel3.core.Bool@32' must be hardware, not a bare Chisel
>   type

It seems the errors are caused by below statements:

```
  val do_enq = io.enq.valid && io.enq.ready && (1.U === init_done) && (0.U === tick_cnt)

  val do_deq = io.deq.ready && io.deq.valid && (1.U === init_done) && (1.U === tick_cnt)
```

Comment: when statements val io = new QueueIO(gen, entries) are replaced by below statements:  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val enq = Flipped(Decoupled(gen)) // valid and bits are inputs
    val deq = Decoupled(gen) // valid and bits are outputs
 val count = Output(UInt(log2Ceil(entries + 1).W))
  }) the error log disappeared

Answer (score 0):

You still need to wrap QueueIO with IO, i.e.

```
val io = IO(new QueueIO(gen, entries))
```

Though you may find examples in the wild without the IO wrapper those are using the Chisel **2** backward compatibility mode.